# Эмуляция клавиатуры в свернутых окнах

Tags: python, клавиатура, pywinauto

Мне нужно контролировать клавиатуру только в некоторых **свернутых** окнах. Нашёл максимально подходящее [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996985/send-some-keys-to-inactive-window-with-python), но с ним есть проблема - работает оно только с блокнотом и подобными приложениями для редактирования текста.

Пробовал также с *pywinauto*, но и тут столкнулся с проблемой - у приложения в которое будет осуществляться ввод текста должен быть особый хэндлер для приёма текста.

Подскажите, как можно отправлять события о нажатии определенных клавиш в свернутые окна любых программ.

Comment: Насчёт любых - вряд ли возможно. Но можно попробовать вот эти методы в pywinauto: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html#tricks-to-run-automation-on-a-locked-machine (если для залоченной машины сгодится, то и для свёрнутого окна, возможно, тоже, но надо проверять).

Comment: Судя по всему, с Win32 API знакомство слабое. У всех окон есть "хэндл" (handle), а не хэндлер. Но эту требуху pywinauto скрывает. Правда, надо немного концепцию вкурить для начала: либо [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html), либо на русском: [Хабрастатья](https://habr.com/ru/post/323962/).